# Using Hash::extract() on Array from Xml

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4, cakephp-2.4.7

I have an array as follows:

```
array(
    'items' => array(
        'item' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                '@item' => '3-394-001068-00000'),
            (int) 1 => array(
                '@item' => '3-394-001069-00000'),
            )
     )
)
```

I am trying to extract all the 'item' entries to a new array.

Here is my code so far:

```
$xmlarray = Xml::toArray(Xml::build(WWW_ROOT .'files/itemsAll/'.$file));

            debug($xmlarray);
            $results = Hash::extract($xmlarray, '{n}.item');

            debug ($results);
```

but this returns only an empty array.
Could someone maybe give me a hint where I'm going wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't crystal clear from your question, but I assume this array

```
array(
    'items' => array(
        'item' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                '@item' => '3-394-001068-00000'),
            (int) 1 => array(
                '@item' => '3-394-001069-00000'),
```

is the result of your `debug($xmlarray);`, so we can rule out misslocation of a file (if I'm assuming wrong, do tell).

So, the hash is your problem.

See, according to [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#expression-types), the `{n}` refers to "a numeric key", and "items" is clearly not. If you want to extract all "item" inside "items", it should be

```
Hash::extract($xmlarray, 'items.item');
```

and that will give you

```
array((int) 0 => array(
                '@item' => '3-394-001068-00000'),
            (int) 1 => array(
                '@item' => '3-394-001069-00000'),
/*etc*/
```

and, if you want to have a much compact array (don't know if you need the index associations), you could try

```
Hash::extract($xmlarray, 'items.item.{n}.@item');
```

and that'll get you

```
array('3-394-001068-00000', '3-394-001069-00000')
```

Comment: Hello Nunser, thanks a lot for your fast answer. Your Code does what i wanted my code to do:-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are better ways to extract information from XML files than converting to an Array and then using `Hash::extract()`.  Cake's [XML library](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html) returns a SimpleXML object by default, so [read up on the docs on that](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for how to extract information directly from the XML.  Specifically, the [`xpath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method may be of use to you.  Your use might look something like this:

```
<?php
$xmlobj = Xml::build(WWW_ROOT .'files/itemsAll/'.$file);
$items = $xmlobj->xpath('/items/item');
?>
```

And then you can iterate through the $items object to do whatever you need to with the elements.

That said, if you're insistent on using `Hash::extract()`, looking at the dumped array, your `item` entries aren't under a numeric key, so `{n}` won't work to access them.  You probably want either `items.item`, or if they can be under keys other than just 'items', `{s}.item`.

Comment: Hello cincodenada, thanks also to you for your fast answer and helping me. Your example works also fine for me, so now i have to check which solution ist faster for data-volume.